# Tomcat 7 - inexplicable multiple instances of singleton

Tags: tomcat, singleton

Just wondering if anyone knows why I experienced this, or if it is a known defect:

My app uses embedded Tomcat 7.0.39. I have a singleton that follows Josh Bloch's enum singleton pattern.  Under 7.0.39, it is indeed a singleton, ie I can verify that only one instance is instantiated. In my pom.xml file, I simply upgraded to 7.0.57, and I saw that the "singleton" got instantiated twice.

What's up with that?!?

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is really only a singleton per class loader. In the case of a Java EE container (even a servlet container like tomcat) there is a different class loader per web app (war). In the case that you stop/start the war, you will get yet another class loader, causing a new instance of the singleton to potentially be created.